# Sumifs formula with dynamic date range is not working in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Here O column is my sum range,
P2 = Date i.e. `2019-05-02`

I want to sum all O column range on the bases of the last 30 days. i.e. `p2-30`.

This formula is working fine in Excel but not working in Google Sheets.

```
=SUMIFS(O:O,C:C,C2,P:P,"<"&TEXT(P2-30,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

I am really new to this and would appreciate any hints.....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give the QUERY function a try.

In

```
F1:  =text(today()-30;"yyyy-mm-dd")
H1:  =query(O1:P18;"Select sum(O) where P> date '"&F1&"'")
```

In case you don't want a header

```
H1: =query(O1:P18;"Select sum(O) where P> date '"&F1&"' label sum(O) ''")
```

QUERY is a very nice function. Using a date can be a bit tricky, look for examples at https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/query-dates/

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(O1:P, "select O 
                         where P <= date '"&TEXT(C2, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
                           and P >= date '"&TEXT(C2-30, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]